# Android Kotlin Take only the data from a sqlite column and fill in an autocompleteTextView

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, adapter

I'm taking data from a table in sqlite and trying to fill it in an autoCompleteTextView.
The database is working perfectly, and the query apparently is too.
However, when passing the data returned from the query, I am unable to pass only the data to the Adapter, without the column name.

For example:

Incorrect return:CatDespModel(category = Internet)

Correct return: Internet

These are my two functions that fetch the data from the database and populate the adapter

```
    fun readCatDesp():ArrayList<CatDespModel>{
        val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(requireContext())
        val listaGeral: ArrayList<CatDespModel> =databaseHandler.readCatDesp()
        return listaGeral
    }

    fun iniDropDown() {
        val accateg:AutoCompleteTextView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.ac_DespAdd_Cat)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<CatDespModel>(requireContext(),
         android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, readCatDesp())
        accateg.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
```

This is the command that accesses the database

```
    fun readCatDesp ():ArrayList<CatDespModel>{
        val despList:ArrayList<CatDespModel> = ArrayList<CatDespModel>()
        val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_DESP"
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        var cursor:Cursor? = null

        try{
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null)

        }catch (e:SQLiteException){
            db.execSQL(selectQuery)
            return ArrayList()
        }
        var id:Int
        var categoria:String
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))
                categoria = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("categoria"))
                val despModel = CatDespModel(
                    categoria = categoria)
                despList.add(despModel)
            }while(cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        return despList
    }
```

This is my model:

```
data class CatDespModel (
    val categoria:String


)
```

Thank you all